# Tangle Emacs Configuration Externally

Tags: org-mode, config

I'd like to tangle the emacs configuration externally, instead of doing it from inside emacs.

It's really hard to debug if the tangle is done in init.el

How can I tangle the configuration org-file from outside of Emacs, then call that .el file from init.el?;)

Answer (score 0):

Org literate configs rely on `babel` to tangle their source into a .el file that emacs reads. That means that, luckily for us, there is no reason that the tangling process has to stay within just emacs. [There are plenty of org-tangle implementations available online to choose from](https://github.com/OrgTangle).

I will show a method available to Doom Emacs users, since that project has an accessible on/off switch for literate configs. The `org-tangle` script  can be used from the command line. (If you are using doom emacs, `org-tangle` is provided in `.emacs.d/bin/org-tangle`.)

From the docstring of `org-tangle`:

```
;; Usage: org-tangle [[-l|--lang] LANG] some-file.org another.org
;; Examples:
;;   org-tangle -l sh modules/some/module/README.org > install_module.sh
;;   org-tangle -l sh modules/lang/go/README.org | sh
;;   org-tangle --and tagA --and tagB my/literate/config.org
```

In summary: Use a `org-tangle` script from your terminal to tangle your config outside emacs.

Edit: As @mmmmmm has noted in the comments below, the tanglers I posted here do not have `noweb` support for references. This may pose limitations on certain use cases for tangling outside emacs. If you know of an org-tangler with `noweb_ref` support, please post a comment to this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately no of these support noweb references so are in effect not of much use.

Comment: great, but how about calling this org-tangle from inside emacs, but actually calling the resulting .el file for the config? That would mean emacs could give sensible errors when something goes wrong?;)

Comment: Like any other shell command, you can use `M-x shell-command` to run a script from emacs. You can then load your resulting config using `(setq user-init-file "path/here")` and `(load user-init-file)`. If you aren't looking to load the config (I am not sure what "run the resulting file" means for elisp source), you can run a standard `eval` command with the expected file name as input.

Comment: @mmmmmm If noweb is needed, I found worgle which claims to support noweb. I have not tested it myself so I can't confirm the claim, but here's the link: https://paulbatchelor.github.io/proj/worgle/

Comment: @MalleYeno That does not seem to allow noweb_ref - just names via NAME

Comment: @mmmmmm Oh, I did not realize. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I run standard Emacs; is org-tangle part of that?

Comment: Yep! Check out the function documentation on `org-babel-tangle.` This provides a link to the file `ob-tangle.el` in the help page. Standard org mode uses babel to tangle source code blocks.