# org-tangle, Where is it?

Tags: tangle

I'm trying to tangle my Emacs configuration file from shell.

I asked a question and was told to use org-tangle, but where is that?

I also tried ntangle, but that failed silently.

Also, I tried this command, but where does it output to?;)

```
emacs --batch --eval "(require 'org)" --eval '(org-babel-tangle-file "emacsen.org")'
```

Comment: https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html

Answer (score 0):

ok, my org file was a symlink, so the output was in the directory it was pointing at;)

I never found org-tangle, but I guess I don't need it now;)

Also, I've filed a bug on ntangle, so I'll follow that over there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find where a function is defined via `C-h f` followed by the function name (or via `M-x find-function` if the function has already been loaded).

`org-babel-tangle-file` is in ob-tangle.el however, `ob-tangle` also gets loaded when loading `org`, so that your current command should work fine.

If you do `C-h f` `org-babel-tangle-file` then you will find that it also takes an optional `TARGET-FILE` argument.

If you do not provide a target-file argument, then the output file will have the same name as the original, but ending in .el instead of .org, and it will be located in the same directory as your original file.

Comment: No, I meant org-tangle, which is a shell command. In some other thread here, they say that this command is included with Doom Emacs;)

Comment: Ah okay. It would be handy to mention that in your question, and also include a link to that thread.

Comment: Actually, I did mention it, saying "from shell";). Also, here's the other thread: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74280/tangle-emacs-configuration-externally

Comment: "(If you are using doom emacs, org-tangle is provided in .emacs.d/bin/org-tangle.)"